# Storing multiple locations for users MySQL

Tags: mysql, ios

So basically I have an app that when a user presses a certain button, their location gets stored in a database. The question is because there could theoretically be thousands of different locations for users when they press this button, how do I store it?

The idea I had is similar to the way you can store a user's friends on a social network, that is, have one column for the userID (email, or whatever) and then another column for their location. So something like the following:

```
_________________________________
| id |      email    | location |
| 1  | test@test.com | 123.456  |
| 2  | test@test.com | 456.2533 |
| 3  | test@test.com | 45345.23 |
| 4  | mail@mail.com | 123.456  |
| 5  | mail@mail.com | 456.2533 |
| 6  | mail@mail.com | 45345.23 |
```

In the case above the 'id' is the primary key and there are two users who happen to have been to the same three locations.

Is this a ridiculous way to store it as it could amount to a lot of data? Or am I on the right track?

Comment: You could make the email address the primary key... theoretically email address to person is a 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: Yes, but if I do that, then I can only have one location for each user, because two primary keys can't be the same.

Comment: Oh... I thought you only wanted 1 location per user stored at a time... sorry. It looks like your on an ok track, I would add a time column, too.

Comment: Yeah I planned on storing time as well, was kind of hoping I wasn't right, cause this could be a tonne of data. Cheers dude!

Comment: Databases lurve data - but you could consider storing users in one table and their locations in another table.